# Download/upload still going even though internet is gone

Tags: internet

So sometimes my internet is disappearing and it's probably my internet provider problem, because my neighbors got the same problem. Now what's strange is when internet is gone, I can see using System Monitor that network download/upload is still going on, but just several kilobytes. Why is it showing internet download/upload when internet is completely gone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you're not connected to the internet there will still be data sent from and to your wireless router. It's not from the internet but it's still data and system monitor will treat it as such.

Comment: I don't have router, cable comes directly into my laptop. So what you mean is that my laptop is sending data to my ISP's router and thus my computer sees that as a traffic?

Comment: Most likely. My best guess is that your computer is checking the status of the connection every so often. That's a few kilobytes of data sent back and forth.

Comment: It could be like [this](http://i.imgur.com/KBlHLOx.jpg) where the connection between the internet and your ISP is gone, but you are still connected to your ISP which is where some data is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible issues in this case, but from what you say, I believe that the download/upload connection that you see, is just the connection between your computer and your home router.

So if you are unable to access www.google.com lets say from your browser, your computer tries to communicate to remote servers. But if there is a problem with your Internet Service Provider (ISP), then your computer is probably only connected to your home router. That is what you see...

You can try a *ping* or *traceroute* command on your pc using a terminal to further diagnose the problem.

Hope that helps :-)

Comment: I don't have router, cable comes directly into my laptop. And ping does not detect any traffic.